# From Email Dropdown on Email-to-Case

Tags: community

I have two profiles Profile1 and profile2. For profile1 5 email addresses have been setup and for profile2 another 5 email addresses have been setup in org wide setting. As I am the user of profile1, I should see the 5 email addresses only from FromEmail dropdown.
How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so.Can you please elaborate @Rajib

Answer (score 0):

I came across this situation and Salesforce hasn't provided any method to restrict the email addresses that we can restrict per profile or role or users. Once the email ids are added to OWS all users can see them.

Please vote here to add this functionality in SF.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l82FAAQ